# Método JSON.stringify tarda en responder dentro de una función Jquery.Ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Recién estoy conociendo Ajax y en una aplicación MVC me encuentro con esta función $.Ajax() donde obtengo un objeto JSON que me devuelve una lista de autorizaciones para armar un arbol de checkboxes y seleccionar las áreas donde trabaja o trabajará el usuario que estoy tratando.
Esta función hace que se ejecute un Stored procedure que me devuelve 9000 registros aprox y al convertir estos valores en un string para luego convertirlo en un objeto JSON tarda más de 30 segundos en obtener la respuesta.

Función $.Ajax()

```
function obtenerArbolAutorizaciones() {
var datos;
var usuario = {};
usuario.Id = idUsuarioNuevo; 

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/views/usuarios/index.aspx/obtenerarbolautorizaciones',
    data: "{ 'jdatos': '" + JSON.stringify({ Usuario: usuario }) + "'}", //--> acá eso donde la función se queda esperando a que termine este proceso 
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json"

}).done(
     function (data) {
        datos = null;
        if (data.d != '') {
            datos = JSON.parse(data.d);
        }
        else
            showError(stringErrorConexion);
    }
).fail(
    function (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
        showError(stringErrorConexion);
    }
);
    if (datos != null) {
        $("#jstree_autorizaciones").dynatree({
            checkbox: true,
            selectMode: 3,
            children: datos,
            height: "260px"
        });

    }
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es bajar el tiempo de respuesta de la solicitud o por lo menos que me permita seguir trabajando mientras se cargan los registros.

Dejo unas imágenes con el detalle de la respuesta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualización**
Este es el nuevo código que tengo pero sigue tardando en el `stringify`, además tuve que poner el `Async = false` porque sino no entra a la parte del .done() y el arbol de opciones no se carga.

```
function obtenerArbolAutorizaciones() {
var datos;
var usuario = {};
usuario.Id = idUsuarioNuevo; 

var myJSON = JSON.stringify({ 'Usuario': usuario });

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/views/usuarios/index.aspx/obtenerarbolautorizaciones',
    data: "{ 'jdatos': '" + myJSON + "'}", 
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json"

}).done(
     function (data) {

        datos = null;
        if (data.d != '') {
            datos = JSON.parse(data.d);
        }
        else
            showError(stringErrorConexion);
    }
).fail(
    function (e) {

        console.log(e.message);
        showError(stringErrorConexion);
    }
);

    if (datos != null) {
        $("#jstree_autorizaciones").dynatree({
            checkbox: true,
            selectMode: 3,
            children: datos,
            height: "260px"
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Tarda 30 segundos procesandolo en el servidor, o en tu .done(, donde hace el JSON.parse(data.d) ???

Comment: Tarda donde hace el  JSON.stringify({ Usuario: usuario }), la aplicación se está ejecutando en el servidor

Comment: Prueba, antes del ajax,< var myUsuario =  JSON.stringify({ Usuario: usuario });>
y luego en el ajax 
  <data: "{ 'jdatos': '" + myUsuario  + "'}",>
Y si ves que sigue tardando, en el data, el problema no es tu json.stringify

Comment: Lo había probado de esta manera pero no funciona porque me da un ´´ReferenceError´´ de que 'Usuario' no está declarado. Como recién estoy metiéndome con Ajax hay cosas que todavía no entiendo, como esto, no sé de donde obtiene 'Usuario'. Dentro de la función obtiene los datos, pero fuera de ella no...

Comment: Prueba asi

var usuario = {};
usuario.Id = idUsuarioNuevo; 
var myJSON = JSON.stringify({ 'Usuarios': usuario });

Comment: De esta manera no entra a la función $.Ajax(), la saltea y pasa a la siguiente función por lo que al no haber obtenido los datos me da error.

Comment: Estás mezclando el tiempo del `stringify` con el tiempo de red y el tiempo del servidor; así no hay manera de saber qué es lo que está tardando. La idea de Luciano es correcta, si por alguna razón te sigue fallando puedes abrir las "Herramientas de desarrollador" de tu navegador y ver allí cuando se inicia la conexión de red (que es una vez se ha hecho el `stringify`); es menos preciso pero te ayudará a hacerte una idea.

Comment: SI, acabo de acomodar el código como me dijo @LucianoMontañez y de esta manera también tarda en el stringify (esta vez tardó 33 seg.). Ahora subo el código actualizado.

Comment: A ver, que NO ES EL STRINGIFY. El Stringify solo te monta un String, y lo hace ANTES DE QUE EMPIECE LA CONEXIÓN. Lo que te está tardando es EL PROCESO EN EL SERVIDOR y posiblemente EL QUE EL JAVASCRIPT TENGA QUE PROCESAR UN JSON DE 10 MEGABYTES. Nada de eso tiene relación con el STRINGIFY. Modifica tu aplicación para que no devuelva tantos datos de una vez.

Comment: Voto para cerrar la pregunta porque el código mostrado no tiene nada que ver con lo que se pregunta.

Comment: Para borrarte las dudas del stringify , borralo.
data: {
  "Usuario": {
    "Id": idUsuarioNuevo
 }
},

Comment: Perfecto @SJuan76, esto me ayuda un poco a entender como funciona, ¿leíste la parte donde dije que recien empiezo con Ajax y hay cosas que todavía no entiendo como funcionan?. La plaicación tiene que trabajar si o sí con esa cantidad de datos, buscaré alguna otra manera de trabajarlos

Comment: Puedes enviar únicamente el objeto, y en el back lo modificas lo tratas. También puedes tratar usando .serialize()

Comment: Si @LucianoMontañez, ya lo había probado. Tengo la misma función para otra cosa y funciona perfecto, pero en este caso estaba obviando la cantidad de datos para tratar con la que trabaja el stringify

Comment: @PabloMatias realmente no creo que necesites mostrar 9000 registros en una sola llamada, modifica tu sp para que te de los registros en grupos de 10, 20 o 50, y con la ayuda de **paginadores** puedes mostrar estos resultados, en cada interacción vuelves a consultar a la db con tus llamadas Ajax. O si de plano es necesario todos esos registros, entonces cuando hagas la llamada a tu sp también mandas un efecto de barra de carga.

Comment: son `4` requests `9.7 mb` transferidos, en `30` segundos es bastante normal (aprox `330kbs`). el problema será mayor en redes mas lentas o inestables